# Hodge star operator : inner product of $k$-forms independent of orthogonal frames

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, differential-geometry, manifolds, exterior-algebra

I'm trying to work out John Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds problem 16-18 about the definition of Hodge star operator, but mainly subproblem (a), I can prove the rest of them assuming the property of (a).

Problem (a) asks you to prove that for each $k=1,\cdots n$, the Riemannian metric $g$ uniquely determines an inner product on $\Lambda^k T^*_p M$ which satisfies

$$\langle \omega^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge \omega^k, \tau^1 \wedge \cdots\tau^k \rangle=\mathrm{det}(\langle(\omega^i)^\sharp,(\tau^j)^\sharp\rangle)$$

where $\omega^1, \cdots, \omega^k,\tau^1, \cdots, \tau^k$ are covectors at $p$. The hint is to define inner product locally by declaring $\{\varepsilon^I|_p :I$ is increasing$\}$ to be an orthonormal frame, whenever $(\varepsilon^i)$ is the coframe dual to a local orthonormal frame.

Here is what I tried following the hint: Every $k$-form locally can be uniquely written as  $\alpha=\sum_{I \nearrow}a_I\varepsilon^I$ where $I$ is an increasing multi-index of length $k$. If we have another $k$-form $\beta=\sum_{I \nearrow}b_I\varepsilon^I$, we define $$\langle\alpha,\beta\rangle=\sum_{I \nearrow}a_Ib_I$$ We must prove the above definition is independent of the choice of coframe: If $(\varepsilon^i)$ and $(\eta^i)$ are two coframes, each of which is dual to an orthonormal frame, $\alpha=\sum_{I \nearrow}a_I\varepsilon^I=\sum_{I \nearrow}a_I^\prime\eta^I$, $\beta=\sum_{I \nearrow}b_I\varepsilon^I=\sum_{I \nearrow}b_I^\prime\eta^I$, then $\sum_{I \nearrow}a_Ib_I=\sum_{I \nearrow}a_I^\prime b_I^\prime$. Suppose $$(\varepsilon^1,\cdots,\varepsilon^n)=(\eta^1,\cdots,\eta^n)\begin{pmatrix} q^1_1 & \cdots 
 & q^n_1 \\ \vdots 
& &\vdots \\q^1_n &\cdots &q^n_n\end{pmatrix}$$
where the matrix $Q=(q^j_i)$ is orthogonal, therefore $\varepsilon^k=\eta^i q^k_i$. Substituting $\varepsilon=\varepsilon^{i_1}\wedge\cdots\wedge\varepsilon^{i_k}$, we have

$$\alpha = \sum_{I \nearrow}a_I^\prime\eta^I=\sum_{I \nearrow}a_I(\sum^n_{j=1}\eta^j q^{i_1}_j\wedge\cdots \wedge \sum^n_{j=1}\eta^j q^{i_k}_j)$$
Fix an multi-index $L=(l_1,\cdots, l_k)$ and compare the coefficients of $\eta^L$, we have
$$a_L^\prime=(\sum_{I \nearrow}a_I \sum_{\sigma \in S_k}(-1)^{\mathrm{sgn}\sigma}q^{i_{\sigma(1)}}_{l_1}\cdots q^{i_{\sigma(k)}}_{l_k})=\sum_{I \nearrow}a_I Q(L,I)$$
where $Q(L,I)$ denotes the minor of $Q$ of row $L$ and column $I$. By the same argument we have $b_L^\prime=\sum_{I \nearrow}b_I Q(L,I)$. So finally what we have to prove is (if I did't make calculation mistakes) given an orthogonal matrix $Q$ and real numbers $a_I,b_I$,
$$\sum_{I \nearrow} a_I b_I=\sum_{(I \nearrow}(\sum_{J \nearrow}a_J Q(I,J))(\sum_{J \nearrow}b_J Q(I,J)))$$
which seems like a tricky linear algebra problem. Do you have any ideas about this, or just give another approach. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe you have misquoted Lee. You’re referring to orthogonal frames and coframes when it should be *orthonormal*.

Comment: see   https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3134/whats-your-favorite-equation-formula-identity-or-inequality/17139#17139  for a cute related item

Comment: I think the "Generalization" section of [this Cauchy-Binet formula article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Binet_formula) gives exactly what you want.

Comment: The other (I think better) approach is to first spend some time with abstract algebra. Specifically with the universal property of exterior powers of vector spaces, which states that if you have an alternating multilinear map, then there is a unique linear map out of the exterior power such that a certain diagram commutes. By applying this repeatedly, you can prove that inner products on $V$ induce inner products on every exterior power $V$ (likewise for $V^*$). Universal properties are your best friend when dealing with quotients/tensor products/exterior powers etc

Comment: See exercises 6-7 page 206 of https://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/16915/2018/04/linalg.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\newcommand\Ext{{\textstyle\bigwedge}}
\newcommand\trans[1]{#1^{\mathrm T}}
\newcommand\form[1]{\langle#1\rangle}
\newcommand\K{\mathbb K}
\newcommand\Tensor{{\textstyle\bigotimes}}
\newcommand\tensor\otimes
\newcommand\lintr{\mathbin\lrcorner}
\newcommand\End{\mathrm{End}}
\newcommand\EndOp{\End_{\mathrm{op}}}
$

I'm going to start with demonstrating how my comment gives the desired result, then prove the key formula, then give an abstract approach to constructing the inner product on $\Ext V$ that doesn't involve any coordinates or bases.

### Generalized Cauchy-Binet Formula

The key result in your notation is
$$
  (AB)(I, K) = \sum_{J\nearrow} A(I, J)B(J, K),
$$
from which it follows that
$$
  \sum_{I\nearrow} Q(I, J)Q(I, K)
    = \sum_{J\nearrow} \trans Q(J, I)Q(I, K)
    = (\trans QQ)(J, K)
    = \delta_{J,K},
$$
so the RHS of your last equation becomes
$$\begin{aligned}
  &\sum_{I\nearrow}\left(\sum_{J\nearrow}a_JQ(I, J)\right)
                  \left(\sum_{J\nearrow}b_JQ(I, J)\right)
\\
    &\qquad= \sum_{J\nearrow}\sum_{K\nearrow}a_Jb_K\sum_{I\nearrow}Q(I, J)Q(I, K)
\\
    &\qquad= \sum_{J\nearrow}\sum_{K\nearrow}a_Jb_K\delta_{J,K}
\\
    &\qquad= \sum_{J\nearrow}a_Jb_J.
\end{aligned}$$

#### Proof

From here on, we will only talk about the exterior algebra over an $n$-dimensional vector space $V$ with field of scalars $\K$ equipped with a symmetric bilinear form $\form{\cdot,\cdot} : V\times V \to \K$; the Riemannian structure plays no part in this beyond giving us this form on the tangent space, i.e. the metric.

The *exterior algebra* $\Ext V$ can be defined as the unique-up-to-isomorphism associative algebra with inclusion $V \to \Ext V$ that has the following *universal property*: for any associative algebra $A$ and linear $f : V \to A$ such that $f(v)^2 = 0$ for all $v \in V$, there is a *unique* algebra homomorphism $g : \Ext V \to A$ such that $g(v) = f(v)$ for $v \in V$. In other words, $f$ uniquely lifts to a homomorphism on $\Ext V$.

Given any linear $f : V \to V$, we can widen the codomain and consider it as a map $V \to \Ext V$, and trivially $f(v)\wedge f(v) = 0$. So there is a unique extension of $f$ to a homomorphism $\Ext V \to \Ext V$, the *outermorphism $f_\wedge$*. Since they take vectors to vectors, outermorphisms are grade-preserving. The space $\Ext^{\!n} V$ is one-dimensional, so there is a unique scalar, the *determinant $\det(f)$*, such that
$$
  f_\wedge(I) = (\det f)I,\quad I \in \Ext^{\!n} V.
$$
Every simple multivector $J$ uniquely determines a subspace $[J] \subseteq V$ by
$$
  v \in [J] \iff v \wedge J = 0.
$$
Given simple $m$-vectors $J, K$, there are orthogonal projections $P_J, P_K$ onto $[J], [K]$; the *$(J,K)$-minor $\det_{J,K}(f)$* of $f$ is the unique scalar such that
$$
  (P_J\circ f\circ P_K)_\wedge(K) = (\det_{J,K}f)J.
$$

You should convince yourself that the minors of the matrix of $f$ in an orthonormal basis $\{e_i\}$ are exactly the $(J,K)$-minors where
$$
  J = e_1\wedge\cdots\wedge e_{j-1}\wedge e_{j+1}\wedge\cdots e_n,\quad
  K = e_1\wedge\cdots\wedge e_{k-1}\wedge e_{k+1}\wedge\cdots e_n
$$
for each $j, k$. In fact, if $J = e_{j_1}\wedge\cdots\wedge e_{j_m}$ and $K = e_{k_1}\wedge\cdots\wedge e_{k_m}$, then $\det_{J,K}(f)$ is the determinant of the matrix with entries $(f_{j_a,k_b})_{a,b=1}^m$.

It is now straight-forward to prove the generalized Cauchy-Binet formula. Let $J, L$ be simple $m$-vectors, and suppose $U = [K_1]\oplus\cdots\oplus[K_k] \subseteq V$ is an $m$-dimensional subspace with $K_1,\dotsc, K_k$ simple $m$-vectors and $[K_1], \dotsc, [K_k]$ mutually orthogonal. Then for any $g : V \to U$ and $f : U \to V$
$$\begin{aligned}
  \Bigl[(P_J)_\wedge\circ f_\wedge\circ g_\wedge\circ(P_L)_\wedge\Bigr](L)
    &= [(P_J)_\wedge\circ f_\wedge]\left(\sum_{i=1}^k K_i\det_{K_i,L}g\right)
\\
    &= \sum_{i=1}^k [(P_J)_\wedge\circ f_\wedge\circ (P_{K_i})_\wedge](K_i)\det_{K_i,L}g
\\
    &= J\sum_{i=1}^k(\det_{J,K_i}f)(\det_{K_i,L}g),
\end{aligned}$$
where we've used the fact the outermorphism of a composition is the composition of the outer morphisms, and that $K_i = (P_{K_i})_\wedge(K_i)$. The first equality follows since $(P_U)_\wedge = \sum_{i=1}^k(P_{K_i})_\wedge$ (which is specifically a result of the $[K_i]$ be mutually orthogonal). Hence
$$
  \det_{J,L}f\circ g = \sum_{i=1}^k(\det_{J,K_i}f)(\det_{K_i,L}g).
$$

### The Natural Pairing $\Ext V^*\times\Ext V$

Let $\Tensor V$ denote the tensor algebra of $V$. It has the universal property that every linear map $V \to A$ with $A$ an associative algebra extends to a homomorphism $\Tensor V \to A$. We will not distinguish the original map from the extended map.

Let $\omega : V \to V$ be a linear involution; considered as map into $\Tensor V$, it extends to an algebra involution on $\Tensor V$. Every linear $f : V \to \Tensor V$ then defines a unique $\omega$-derivation $\Omega_f : \Tensor V \to \Tensor V$ by
$$
  \Omega_f(1) = 0,\quad \Omega_f(v) = f(v),\quad
  \Omega_f(v\tensor X) = f(v)\tensor X + \omega(v)\tensor \Omega_f(X)
$$
for $v \in V$ and $X \in \Tensor^kV$.
It can be confirmed that this gives a well defined map, and that it is indeed a derivation:
$$
  \Omega_f(X\tensor Y) = \Omega_f(X)\tensor Y + \omega(X)\tensor\Omega_f(Y).
$$

The exterior algebra can be realized as a quotient $\Ext V = \Tensor V/I$ where $I$ is the two-sided ideal generated by $\{v\tensor v \;:\; v \in V\}$. As such, every map $f : V \to \Ext V$ lifts to a (non-unique) map $f' : V \to \Tensor V$, which gives a unique derivation $\Omega_{f'}$. It can be confirmed that $\Omega_{f'}$ maps $I$ to $I$ if
$$
  \Omega_{f'}(v\tensor v) = f'(v)\tensor v + \omega(v)\tensor f'(v) \in I
$$
for all $v \in V$, and this condition descends to $\Ext V$ as
$$
  f(v)\wedge v + \omega(v)\wedge f(v) = 0.
$$
Under this condition, $f$ extends to a unique $\omega$-derivation on $\Ext V$.

Now, for any $\alpha \in V^*$ define $\alpha\lintr v = \alpha(v)$. We choose $\omega(v) = -v$ and confirm
$$
  (\alpha\lintr v)\wedge v + (-v)\wedge(\alpha\lintr v)
    = (\alpha\lintr v)v - (\alpha\lintr v)v
    = 0.
$$
So $\alpha\lintr$ extends to an antiderivation; note that it takes grade $k$ to grade $k-1$. So now we have a map
$$
  \alpha \mapsto \alpha\lintr : V^* \to \End(\Ext V)
$$
into the linear endomorphisms of $\Ext V$. Here we have a choice; we can take this as is, or map it into the opposite algebra $\EndOp(\Ext V)$ (which is $\End(\Ext V)$ with its multiplication reversed). It turns out the inner product you want corresponds to the $\EndOp(\Ext V)$ choice. We can confirm that
$$
  [(\alpha\lintr)\circ(\alpha\lintr)](X) = \alpha\lintr(\alpha\lintr X) = 0
$$
for all $X$, and so $\alpha \mapsto \alpha\lintr$ extends to a homomorphism $\Ext V^* \to \EndOp(\Ext V)$, i.e. an *antihomomorphism* $\Ext V^* \to \End(\Ext V)$ which acts like a homomorphism but reverses products. This property implies
$$
  \omega\lintr X \in \Ext^{\!l-k}V \quad\text{for}\quad \omega \in \Ext^{\!k} V^*,\quad X \in \Ext^{\!l} V.
$$

We finally define the natural pairing $\Ext V^*\times\Ext V \to \K$ by
$$
  \form{\omega, X} = \form{\omega\lintr X}_0
$$
where $\form\cdot_0$ selects the scalar component. For $\omega^1,\dotsc,\omega^k \in V^*$ and $v_1,\dotsc,v_k \in V$, we can use the fact that $\omega^i\lintr$ is an antiderivation to show that
$$\begin{aligned}
  \form{\omega^1\wedge\cdots\wedge\omega^k,\:
        v_1\wedge\cdots\wedge v_k}
    &= (\omega^1\wedge\cdots\wedge\omega^k)\lintr(v_1\wedge\cdots\wedge v_k)
\\
    &= \omega^k\lintr\omega^{k-1}\lintr\cdots\lintr\omega^1\lintr(v_1\wedge\cdots\wedge v_k)
\\
    &= \det\bigl(\omega^i(v_j)\bigr)_{i,j=1}^k,
\end{aligned}$$
where we've used the convention that $\lintr$ is right-associative. The musical isomorphism $\sharp, \flat$ extend to an isomorphism between $\Ext V^*$ and $\Ext V$, and allow us to transfer this pairing to those spaces:
$$
  \form{X, Y} = \form{X^\flat\lintr Y}_0,\quad \form{\omega, \eta} = \form{\omega\lintr\eta^\sharp}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Follow Nicholas Todoroff's hint (generalized Cauchy-Binet Formula), we have
$$\sum_{I}(\sum_{J}a_J Q(I,J))(\sum_{J }b_J Q(I,J)))=\sum_{I }\sum_{J,K}a_Jb_KQ(I,J)Q(I,K)=\sum_{J,K}\sum_{I }a_Jb_KQ(I,J)Q(I,K)=\sum_{J,K}a_Jb_KI(J,K)=\sum_{J,K}a_Jb_K\delta^{JK}=\sum_{I} a_I b_I$$